# How to compile sum over the compiled expression?

Tags: compile, code-review, broken-code

Consider the following toy code:

```
table = Table[{i^0.11, i^0.005}, {i, 1, 1000, 0.5}];
val = Compile[{{table, _Real, 2}, {i, _Integer}}, table[[i]][[1]], CompilationOptions -> 
 "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> 
  True, CompilationTarget -> "C"]
sum = Hold@
    Compile[{{table, _Real, 2}}, 
     Sum[val[table, i], {i, 1, Length[table], 1}], CompilationOptions -> 
 "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> 
  True, CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True] /. OwnValues@val //
   ReleaseHold
```

where I define compiled value `val[table,i]`, and then compiled sum over i, `sum[table]`. I get error

```
Function::flpar: Parameter specification {table,1} in {table,1}\[Function]table[[1]][[1]] should be a symbol or a list of symbols.
```

Could you please tell me how to have the compile the sum over i? I need this since in realistic case `table` is also a (very complicated) compiled function, and I also **cannot** omit the intermediate definition `val`, as there are too many intermediate actions that I need to get in order to obtain `val`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inlining is really not `Compile`'s strength. I got it working though by declaring an accumulator `a` and by replacing `Sum` by a `Do` loop.

```
table = Table[{i^0.11, i^0.005}, {i, 1, 1000, 0.5}];

val = Compile[{{table, _Real, 2}, {i, _Integer}},
   Compile`GetElement[table, i, 1],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

sum = With[{val = val},
   Compile[{{table, _Real, 2}},
    Block[{a},
     a = val[table, 1];
     Do[a += val[table, i], {i, 2, Length[table], 1}];
     a
     ],
    
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True},
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
```

Note however that this is very inefficient, because `Compile` does not really inline; when tensors are involved, it typically adds a `CopyTensor` for each inlined call to `val` -- and that's just to extract a single number from the array. That means: `"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True` enforces call by value! This is really a total performance killer for `Compile` and the reason why I moved to directly programming in C++ via LibraryLink for complicated work flows.

If you insist on using `Compile` (which I would understand because that was my own practice for a long time), then I would suggest to also measure the performance of `"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False`. Depending on the workload, it might be faster even though not inlined.

**Edit**

Just to demonstate how inefficient this is, let's compare with the manually inlined version below:

```
sum2 = With[{val = val}, Compile[{{table, _Real, 2}},
    Block[{a},
     a = Compile`GetElement[table, 1, 1];
     Do[a += Compile`GetElement[table, i, 1], {i, 2, Length[table],1}];
     a
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
```

Here the comparison:

```
table = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100000, 10}];
result = sum[table]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result2 = sum2[table]; // RepeatedTiming // First
result == result2
```

> 0.872045
>
> 0.000093828
>
> True

So the first version takes more than 50000(!) times longer.

Comment: Why does the code use Compile`GetElement[table, i, 1] rather than table[[i,1]] ?

Comment: Does your comment about CopyTensor mean that generally, computations involving matrices are slow with Compile? I am noticing that Compile is quite slow at building a 100x100x32x32 tensor (takes a few seconds)

Comment: "Why does the code use ``Compile`GetElement[table, i, 1]`` rather than ``table[[i,1]]``?" Because ``Compile`GetElement`` skips the bound checks and is thus faster.

Comment: "Does your comment about CopyTensor mean that generally, computations involving matrices are slow with Compile?" There are a few workarounds, but in general yes, writing complicated code for multidimensional arrays is often more efficient when it is done with plain C code via LibraryLink instead with `Compile`.